# /usr/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:283:11: error: expression cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++, enums, c++17, std, stdarray

I have the following minimal example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

enum my_enum {
    onething,
    otherthing
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::array<my_enum, 20> a_variable;
    if (std::none_of(a_variable.begin(), a_variable.end(), onething)) {
        std::cout << "Some Text\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.3.0/algorithm:61,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<_Predicate>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = my_enum*; _Predicate = my_enum]’:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:120:14:   required from ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = my_enum*; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<my_enum>]’
/usr/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:161:23:   required from ‘_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = my_enum*; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<my_enum>]’
/usr/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:3932:28:   required from ‘_IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = my_enum*; _Predicate = my_enum]’
/usr/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:526:47:   required from ‘bool std::none_of(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = my_enum*; _Predicate = my_enum]’
test.cpp:12:65:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:283:11: error: expression cannot be used as a function
  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As far as I could tell from other SO-answers this occurs when one tries to assign the same name to a variable and a function or forgets a multiplication symbol in a formula (as in `5(6)`). However here the error occurs in the standard library, so I don't think that's the issue.

Why is this error occuring and what should I modify to be able to compile my code?

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). More specifically we need to know what `OwnKing` is.

Comment: [This `std::all_of`, `std::any_of` and `std::none_of` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `std::none_of` expects a function-like object (e.g. a lambda-function), not a value for comparison.

This works:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

enum my_enum {
    onething,
    otherthing
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::array<my_enum, 20> a_variable;
    if (std::none_of(a_variable.begin(), a_variable.end(), [](my_enum somevar){return somevar==onething;})) {
        std::cout << "Some Text\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```